# Autocomplete attribute using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, autocomplete, safari, reactjs

I'm trying to use autoComplete attribute for credit card details on 's (not wrapped in any form) but it is not working.

Any guesses? Is https required for autocomplete to work?

I've tried the following using Safari and Chrome:

`<input type='text' placeholder='xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx' value={this.state.card} autoComplete='on' />`

`<input type='text' placeholder='xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx' value={this.state.card} autoComplete='cc-number' />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer. That didn't work for me.
I just figured out: Using `name` and `id` props with `cc_number` value and of course, not running the project on localhost, works.

```
<input type='text' name='cc_number' id='cc_number' ... />
```

For the expiration month and year I used `exp_month` and `exp_year`.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had to wrap all of my inputs in a `<form>` element. Empty was fine.

Comment: You are an angel! I've searched all over the internet for a solution. Have a great life!

Answer (score 0):

Try using it like this:

```
<input autoComplete={'off'}>
```